# VB.NET Expanding an Image while Preventing Clicks on the Form

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, panel, transparent

I am developing a WinForm application using VB.NET (I am fluent in C# as well, so post in whatever language) and have run into some trouble.

I have an image on my form that I would like to expand when clicked on. I have all that logic set, but I want that when it expands, the user has to click on an 'X' in the upper right corner of the PictureBox to close the expanded image. While the image is being displayed, I don't want the user to be able to interact with the rest of the UI on the form.

Basically I need something along the lines of (pardon me for switching to HTML but I know this works there) creating a div that covers the whole screen, making it opaque, putting another div on top of that, and then putting the image and the 'X' button on top of that. I have tried using opaque forms (didn't work), and panels with a transparent backcolor (didn't work either). I've resorted to taking a screenshot of the form, setting it as the image of a PictureBox, and putting the PictureBox on top of that. However, that seems like way to much overkill.

My current layout is MainForm -> Dynamically create new Form and add it to Main Form -> Add PictureBox to Dynamic Form and set its image to be a screenshot of MainForm -> Add a PictureBox on top of that PictureBox and set its image to the expanded image that I want

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, woops. I should add that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you opening the large version in another form? Then something as simple as this in the click event on the picturebox should suffice (sample in c#, but same idea for vb.net)

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmPicture frm = new frmPicture(); //form that has large version of pic
            frm.ShowDialog(); //this makes the form modal
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot about that. It's been driving me nuts for two hours now. *smh*